# Desired perl REST-API output

Tags: xml, perl, rest

I am using the Perl [Apache2::REST](https://metacpan.org/module/Apache2%3a%3aREST) module and the standard way of returning data is to issue `$resp->data()` and assign a value. I have something like this

```
my $text = {
    'tag1' => 4,
    'tag2' => 5,
    'tag3' => 6,
};

$resp->data()->{'text'} = {map { $_ => [$text ->{$_}] } keys %$text};
```

which gives me a response like this

```
<response message="" status="200">
  <data name="text">
    <tag1>4</tag1>
    <tag2>5</tag2>
    <tag3>6</tag3>
  </data>
</response>
```

**Is it possible to change the resulting response to something like the following**

```
<response message="" status="200">
  <content name="text">
    <tag1>4</tag1>
    <tag2>5</tag2>
    <tag3>6</tag3>
  </content>
</response>
```

**What do i need to set/issue?**
I have tried to change the response output - no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (or to be exact one of my colleagues) by inspecting the module code.

REST-API accepts whatever hashkey the user chooses:

```
delete $resp->{data}; # Deletion of the defaulr data element
$resp->{content}->{'text'} = {map { $_ => [$text ->{$_}] } keys %$text};
```